# Having trouble compiling bytecoin on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: bytecoin, c++

I'm trying to compile bytecoin core and when it gets at 31% when trying to compile **BlockchainExplorer.cpp** I get this error:

> ../src/BlockchainExplorer/BlockchainExplorer.cpp: In constructor ‘CryptoNote::BlockchainExplorer::BlockchainExplorer(CryptoNote::INode&, Logging::ILogger&)’:
>   ../src/BlockchainExplorer/BlockchainExplorer.cpp:149:1: error: ‘CryptoNote::BlockchainExplorer::database’ is initialized with itself [-Werror=init-self]
>    **BlockchainExplorer**::BlockchainExplorer(INode& node, Logging::ILogger& logger) :
>   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste the source line in question, as well as a few lines before and after it for context ? I think the solution is simple, but I'd like to make sure my assumption matches the reality of the source.